# Solve integral using integration by parts

Tags: integration

Can someone point out where my mistake is in this integration problem. I know that it can be solved in another way but I wanted to solve it using ontegration by parts method. Is it not possible to solve it using this method or am I missing something. It is driving me crazy.

Here is a pic of the problem and my solution and the solution that is correct: https://ibb.co/hfjV2G

Comment: You might consider using MathJAX to format specific maths within content here...

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct up till the $uv$ part. You should have 
$$x \sqrt{2x+5}$$
instead.

Comment: It seems that they used $v = \frac{1}{2x + 5}$ instead of $v = \int \frac{1}{2x+5}$ in the rest of the derivation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did make that mistake. However the result is still way off :/

Comment: @Ajla: Possible to upload your new working?